# Template as a variable in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, internationalization, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm creating an internationalized Ember.js app, for which I'm using [Ember-I18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n). This works fine in most scenarios, but now consider the language string:

```
'To do some action {{link}}'
```

Where `{{link}}` needs to be replaced with some link. The translation string cannot be broken up, since the position of `{{link}}` can differ from language to language. So instead I need to find a way to get the link in there; which is of course another template with a translation, something like:

```
<a {{action someAction}}>{{t click_here}}</a>
```

I've tried several things thusfar: creating a custom view for the link, using a custom block helper; but I havent' gotten anything to work yet.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? In other words, how can I get a rendered template as a variable to insert it into another template in Ember.js?

Comment: Is it possible for you to have the link in a fixed position, but have a "before text" and an "after text", where one may be empty if the language requires it so?

Comment: I'm currently working on an app with a similar scenario. I have created all my templates in separate files and then manually copy the handlebars markup of each template to a key in my resource file (I'm doing .net so I have a .resx file for each language I support. I believe rails uses .yml files, right?). It might not be the best way to go as I have to manually copy the whole template to the resource key every time I change it, and deal with spaces and all. Then at runtime, I inject the template source into `Ember.TEMPLATES`. Again, might not be the best way to go, just throwing it out there

Comment: @Jasper That might be possible, however I can already think of a few scenarios in which this isn't sufficient (imagine there being more than one link, the order _might_ not even be accurate). As a workaround I can probably use that (and hope I never run into such an exception case), but I hope there's a better approach.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe One of the issues is that Ember.js actually kind of hijacks Handlebars.js and the templates appear to work slightly differently. As a result the required Ember helpers for this scenario (action, for instance), are unavailable in language "templates"; so unfortunately I can't just use the entire markup.

Comment: Not sure I understand *Ember.js actually kind of hijacks Handlebars.js and the templates appear to work slightly differently*

Comment: Neither do I at this point, but I'm looking into it ;). What I mean is that Ember.Handlebars.compile() behaves differently than Handlebars.compile(). I originally thought of a solution where I used a custom view inside my translation string (`For some action {{view view.clickHereView}}`), but apparently I cannot access the view helper from there since Ember-I18n uses Handlebars.compile instead of Ember.Handlebars.compile and I can't just replace it. This still seems like the most promising approach though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use that library to translate my application, but as I understand from its documentation, this might work:

1) Create a view for the template like this:

```
var view = Em.View.create({
  templateName: "mytemplate",
  link: "http://emberjs.com",
});
```

2) Use in your template the bindings that Ember-I18n provide:

```
<a {{action someAction}}>{{t click_here linkBinding="view.link"}}</a>
```

Assuming that translation string is in the "click_here" key.

More info: https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n#bind-interpolated-values

Comment: But in the situation I mean there is a nested translation; i.e. a template/translation inside the click_here translation. This is not solved by the binding mechanism.